# Dataframe with metrics per row and stimuli average per column. How to do it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mean

I have a very trivial problem but I don't know well the Pandas library and I don't know how to operate.

I have a dataframe where there is the Id of the subjects, and some metrics (A, B, C) repeated for the number of stimuli (Stim_1, Stim_2, etc..)

I need to create from this dataframe another dataframe composed of the averages of each stimulus for the individual metrics.  Till now i wrote

```
 df_mean = pd.DataFrame()
 for col in df:
 m = df[col].mean()
```

Here the original dataframe

[image: Here the original dataframe (df)]

and

here the dataframe I want to create

[image: here the dataframe I want to create]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create `MultiIndex` by all columns without `ID` by `split`, so possible reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with aggregate `mean` by second level:

```
print (df)
   ID  A_Stim1  A_Stim2  A_Stim3  B_Stim1  B_Stim2  B_Stim3
0   1        1        5        6        9        8        7
1   8        1        6        4        5        4        5

df1 = df.set_index('ID')
df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split('_', expand=True, n=1)
df2 = df1.stack(0).groupby(level=1).mean()
print (df2)
   Stim1  Stim2  Stim3
A    1.0    5.5    5.0
B    7.0    6.0    6.0
```

Comment: Hello @jezrael, your code was very useful. But it returns the name of the simulus splitted in two rows. I need to aggregate them! That's the output:

Stim   Stim          Stim
    1            2             3
A mean mean mean
B mean mean mean
C mean mean mean

Comment: @AlessandroF. - Can you add expected ouput from my sample data? What numbers should be there?

Comment: Thank you @jezrael, l I want a script that work indipendently by the structure of stimulus name. In this case (real case of the stimuls name, this is what happens)

https://ibb.co/KKMPqqZ

Comment: @AlessandroF. - then use `df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split('_', expand=True, n=1)` instead `df1.columns = df1.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)` split by first `_`

Comment: thanks! this works correctly. Thank you for the help, I hope this will work indpendently by the stimulus name (it has to be a generic function)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
cols = ['A', 'B', 'C']
# or generic
cols = df.columns.str.extract('([^_]+)_', expand=False).unique()

(pd
 .wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), cols,
               i='index', j='id2', sep='_',
               suffix='Stim\d+') # can also be generic '.+'
 .groupby(level='id2').mean()
 .T
)
```

output (input of same shape as provided, filled with 1s):

```
id2  Stim1  Stim2  Stim3
A      1.0    1.0    1.0
B      1.0    1.0    1.0
C      1.0    1.0    1.0
```

Comment: Hello @mozway, thanks! I need a generic script that works with any df it will arrive, so I cannot do something with column's name! thank you anyway

Comment: @Alessandro you can make it generic, see update ;)